# How to add stock column per each item on sales order search grid at Magento2 admin page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, adminhtml

I think it would be necessary to place an order in admin page. 
I want to show the stock level at order creation (in backend) during product selection stage in the search grid (Sales_Order_Create_Search_Grid).

How can I go about doing this?

This is a solution for Magento1. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069097/magento-show-stock-levels-in-sales-order-create-search-grid

How can i handle with it on Magento2?

Thank you

Comment: I have the same request - any help`?

Comment: Please add this as a comment, this is not an answer

Answer (score 3):

You need to create Vendor_Module and do the following:
Override the **Grid.php** like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid" />
</config>
```

Add the below code to your **Grid.php** in the below location:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Search/Grid.php

Code for **Grid.php**:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search;

class Grid extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid
{
    protected $_salesConfig;
    protected $_sessionQuote;
    protected $_catalogConfig;
    protected $_productFactory;

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'available_qty',
            [
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'header' => __('Available Quantity'),
                'renderer' => \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\Renderer\Availableqty::class,
                'name' => 'available_qty',
                'inline_css' => 'available_qty',
                'type' => 'input',
                'validate_class' => 'validate-number',
                'index' => 'available_qty',
                'sortOrder' => 500
            ]
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

Create one more class **Availableqty.php** under below location:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Search/Grid/Renderer/Availableqty.php

and add the below code:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\Renderer;

class Availableqty extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Text
{
    private $stockItem;
    public function __construct(\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockItem)
    {
        $this->stockItem = $stockItem;
    }
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        return $this->stockItem->getStockQty($row->getId(), $row->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
    }
}
```

Run setup:upgrade and di:compile and test.